# $G$ is additive group $\bmod {88}$. $f$ is known element of subgroup order $8$. Proof that lowest 3 bits of $x$ can be inferred from $xf \bmod 88$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

$G$ is additive group $\bmod {88}$. $f$ is known element of subgroup order $8$. Proof that lowest 3 bits of $x$ can be inferred from $xf \bmod 88$.

$G$ is the additive group of integers modulo $88$.

This group contains one subgroup of order $8$ - these are the elements of this subgroup - $\{0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77\}$.

$f$ is an element of this subgroup. $xf \bmod 88$ is essentially scalar multiplication of the element $f$ of the subgroup of order $8$. So $xf \bmod 88$ will be one of the elements of that subgroup.

I wrote a program where I used $f = 11$

```
for x in range(88):
     varxf = (x*11)% 88
     rem = x%8
     print(str(varxf) + " " +  f' {rem:08b}')
```

From the output it's clear that, for $f=11$

| $11.x$ | $x$ low 3 bits |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 001 |
| 22 | 010 |
| 33 | 011 |
| 44 | 100 |
| 55 | 101 |
| 66 | 110 |
| 77 | 111 |

Likewise for other values of $f$, I can infer the lower $3$ bits of $x$ if I know $xf \bmod 88$.

---

Let me give an example.

If Person $A$ chooses $x = 10$ (I don’t know the value of $x$). $A$ then calculates $10 * 11  \bmod 88$ which is $22$ & gives me this value. The moment, I know 22, I then look at the table above & infer that the $x$ he chose had it’s last 3 bits as $010$

Instead if he chooses $x = 53$ & gives me $53*11 \bmod 88$ (i.e. $55$), I can again look at the table & figure out that he chose some $x$ whose last 3 bits were $101$.

---

I am trying to prove the above formally, that from $xe \bmod 88$, I can infer the lower $3$  bits of $x$

When I try to prove this, I see the following which may be relevant.

- $\bmod 8$ (i.e. the remainder after dividing by $8$) is the lower $3$ bits of the number being divided/mod'ed.
- $88$ is of the form $p * 2^{n}$ where $p$ is a prime & $p$ & $2^{n}$ are co-prime.
- Because of the properties of cyclic subgroups, $11$ is a generator for subgroup of order $8$
- $a \bmod {pq} = a \bmod p = a \bmod q$ (Opp of Chinese Remainder Theorem)

I have been trying this for a couple of days now, but I am unable to proceed beyond figuring out the above points.

I want to end up proving this for a group which is of the form $\bmod {p*2^{n}}$, but for the purpose of this question, I want to just prove it for these specific values $(11, 8, 88)$

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Of course, if we know $n\pmod  {88}$ and we know $n\pmod {11}$ then we know $n\pmod 8$.  That's just the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @lulu - No. The value of $11.x \bmod 88$ is distinct (it is one of 8 elements of the subgroup) depending on the value of $x \bmod 8$ - i.e. if I know the value of $11.x \bmod 88$, I can figure out low 3 bits of x (i.e. $x \bmod 8$). I have verified it by writing a program. But I am trying to prove/derive why it is so

Comment: As I say, what you are writing is not clear.  What is $x$?  It's obvious that multiplying by something divisible by $11$ yields something which is divisible by $11$.

Comment: @lulu - $x$ can be any integer in the world. And I am not asking about the divisible by $11$

Comment: Ok, so let's take $x=10$.  Now, what do you want to say about $x$?

Comment: @lulu - I have updated with an example

Comment: Ok, but you are just doing what I said in the first comment.  You are using the fact that you know $11x \pmod {88}$ and you know $11x \pmod {11}$ to deduce the value of $11x\pmod 8$.  this is just the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @lulu -  I using the value of $11x \bmod 88$ to deduce the value of $x \bmod 8$ & not what you say

Comment: The symbol $e$ is a bad choice for a nontrivial group element.

Comment: @Shaun true - e is identity element. Let me edit it

Comment: Really, it is.  $11x$ is obviously $0\pmod {11}$ and you are relying on that fact.  This is just the Chinese Remainder Theorem, nothing more.

Comment: @Lulu is right, I think

Comment: It's pretty hard to infer anything about $x$ if you know $xf \pmod{88}$ for $f = 0$. So what is the real condition?

Comment: @lulu - hmm, let me think about it!

Comment: You are using the formula $(a \cdot b) \bmod (a \cdot c) = a\cdot(b \bmod c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x = 8q+r$$
$$f = 11g$$
$$\begin{array} {rcl} 
xf \bmod 88 
&=& (8q+r)\cdot 11g \bmod 88 \\
&=& (88qg + 11rg) \bmod 88 \\
&=& 11(rg \bmod 8)
\end{array}$$

So the question is, if someone gives you $(rg \bmod 8)$, can you find $r$?  Depends on if $g$ is even.  If $g = 4$ for example, then $r \in \{2, 4, 6\}$ will all give the same value $11(rg \bmod 8) = 0$.  But for odd $g$, that is for $f \in \{11, 33, 55, 77\}$, then you can find $r$ because $g$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $8$.

Comment: Yes, $g$ cannot be any element of the subgroup. It has to be one of the generators of the subgroup - i.e. one of $\{11, 33, 55, 77\}$

Comment: So my original statement " f is known element of subgroup o rder 8." is wrong & it has to be "f is a generator of the subgroup of order 8" - let me think a little more about this.

Comment: You really shouldn't be bringing up all the stuff about groups and subgroups and orders and generators.  This is simple modular arithmetic.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the above effort is my first step in trying to prove that this will be true for all groups of the form $\pmod {p*2^{n}}$, so I need to frame what $f$ needs to be - I think $f$ needs to be a generator of the subgroup of order $2^n$ & $n$ bits can be inferred

Comment: I think there is a large class of cases where $f = 11g+h$ for $0 < h < 11$ where you can still determine the value of $r$.  With $h=0$  you always get $xf \bmod 88$ as a multiple of $11$ but with $h \ne 0$  you aren't guaranteed that.   And it is related to the problem of finding $(x,y)$ s.t. $Ax + By = C$.